# Rotate 180 degrees screen in HTC Desire HD with ICS from Blackout team

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-desire-hd, auto-rotation

I just installed ICS in my HTC Desire HD (thanks Blackout Team) in [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1531218)

HTC Desire has the charging plug in the bottom, and a coworker was so nice to make me a stand for the phone. PRoblem is I cant charge it while standing.

IS there a way so that I can rotate 180 degrees upside down everything in my screen?

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings > display > rotation. In there you might have the option to enable 180 degrees. This works for me using CM9 so hopefully it works for you.

Comment: I dont have this option. I guess it's a CM9-only option

Comment: That's a pity. Maybe if you changed launcher it might work. I think CM9 uses Trebuchet launcher so if you installed that it might give you the option.